# how to scroll DatePicker when placed in a scrollview

Tags: android, datepicker, android-scrollview

basically I couldnt scroll the months and years in a datepicker because the scrollview is the one scrolling.

```
<DatePicker
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/datePicker5"
            android:layout_weight="3.61"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

what do I need to add? thanks

i also have this code btw.

```
private void addPet(){
    LayoutInflater layoutInflaterAndroid = LayoutInflater.from(c);
    View mView = layoutInflaterAndroid.inflate(R.layout.add_pet_dialog, null);
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilderUserInput = new AlertDialog.Builder(c);
    alertDialogBuilderUserInput.setView(mView);


    final EditText userInputDialogEditText = (EditText) mView.findViewById(R.id.pet_name);
    final DatePicker date_picker = (DatePicker) mView.findViewById(R.id.datepick);
    date_picker.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
        {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                //  Disallow the touch request for parent scroll on touch of datepicker view
                requestDisallowParentInterceptTouchEvent(v, true);
            }
            else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP || event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) {
                // Re-allows parent events
                requestDisallowParentInterceptTouchEvent(v, false);
            }
            return false;
        }
    });



        alertDialogBuilderUserInput
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Send", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogBox, int id) {
                    // ToDo get user input here
                }
            })

            .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogBox, int id) {
                            dialogBox.cancel();
                        }
                    });

    AlertDialog alertDialogAndroid = alertDialogBuilderUserInput.create();
    alertDialogAndroid.show();


}



private void requestDisallowParentInterceptTouchEvent(View v, Boolean disallowIntercept) {
    while (v.getParent() != null && v.getParent() instanceof View) {
        if (v.getParent() instanceof ScrollView) {
            v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(disallowIntercept);
        }
        v = (View) v.getParent();
    }
}
```

I dont know why it still doesnt work pls help.

Answer (score 1):

Having a scrollable view inside another scrollable view is not a good practice. However to solve the problem, you will have to disable the parent scrollview while user is interacting with the date picker, like this -

```
date_picker.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
    {
     if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
      //  Disallow the touch request for parent scroll on touch of datepicker view
      requestDisallowParentInterceptTouchEvent(v, true);
     } 
     else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP || event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) {
     // Re-allows parent events
     requestDisallowParentInterceptTouchEvent(v, false);
     }
    return false;
    }
    });


private void requestDisallowParentInterceptTouchEvent(View v, Boolean disallowIntercept) {
    while (v.getParent() != null && v.getParent() instanceof View) {
        if (v.getParent() instanceof ScrollView) {
            v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(disallowIntercept);
        }
        v = (View) v.getParent();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Dr.DOOM Can you share your complete xml file?

Answer (score 0):

@Basanth This doesn't work in my

```
Android Studio Chipmunk | 2021.2.1 Patch 2
Build #AI-212.5712.43.2112.8815526, built on July 10, 2022
Runtime version: 11.0.12+0-b1504.28-7817840 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Linux 5.19.6-arch1-1
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation.
```

After research I found this solution:

```
datePicker = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datePicker);
svActivity_add_date = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.svActivity_add_date);
svActivity_add_date.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScrollChanged() {
            requestDisallowParentInterceptTouchEvent(datePicker, true);
        }
    });
```

I know that maybe is not the right solution, but it works scrolling years in my LG Leon API 23. If I don't add any code, scrolling years is very, very, very slow.

My HUAWEI P30 lite works fine with or without this code.