# Unable to scroll to choose the year in DatePicker widget in android java

Tags: java, android, android-layout, scroll, datepicker

your text I have a datepicker view in android java that is used in a registration form so that users can give their date of birth, now when the year option is selected to scroll and choose the year user was born in, the year refuses to scroll an inch either up or down so i cannot select the birth year due to this.

I expected the year list to be scrollable so user can easily scroll and select but it isn't, i have tried some stuff chatgpt told me but they didn't work

Here is the xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".ECMainActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:padding="5dp">
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:cardElevation="10dp"
                app:contentPadding="10dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
                app:cardMaxElevation="12dp"
                app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true"
                app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textSize="20dp"
                        android:text="Enter Details"/>
                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                        android:id="@+id/filledTextFieldFirstName"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:hint="Enter First Name">

                        <!--this is the actual edit text which takes the input-->
                        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                            android:id="@+id/firstName"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                        android:id="@+id/filledTextFieldLastName"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:hint="Enter Last Name">

                        <!--this is the actual edit text which takes the input-->
                        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                            android:id="@+id/lastName"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                        android:id="@+id/filledTextFieldPartyName"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:hint="Enter Party Name">

                        <!--this is the actual edit text which takes the input-->
                        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                            android:id="@+id/partyName"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
                    <RadioGroup
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/genderGrp">
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="horizontal">
                            <RadioButton
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:id="@+id/male"
                                android:text="Male"/>

                            <RadioButton
                                android:id="@+id/female"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="Female" />
                            <RadioButton
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:id="@+id/others"
                                android:text="Others"/>
                        </LinearLayout>
                    </RadioGroup>
                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                        android:id="@+id/filledTextFieldAN"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:hint="Enter Aadhar Number">

                        <!--this is the actual edit text which takes the input-->
                        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                            android:id="@+id/aadharNumber"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:cardElevation="10dp"
                app:contentPadding="10dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
                app:cardMaxElevation="12dp"
                app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textSize="20dp"
                        android:text="Choose Date of Birth"/>

                    <DatePicker
                        android:id="@+id/datePicker"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:headerBackground="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
                        android:padding="10px" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:cardElevation="10dp"
                app:contentPadding="10dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
                app:cardMaxElevation="12dp"
                app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textSize="20dp"
                        android:text="Add Aadhar Card Picture"/>
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/chooseFileBtn"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                            android:text="Choose File"
                            app:backgroundTint="#4CAF50" />

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/submitBtn"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:text="Submit Details"
                            app:backgroundTint="#FF5722" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:visibility="gone"
                        android:id="@+id/uploadEC"
                        android:orientation="vertical">
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:text="Processing..."/>
                        <ProgressBar
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/goBackToInfoPage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="Go Back To Info"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                app:backgroundTint="#2196F3" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess your problem is that you have your datepicker inside scrollview. Can you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42294154/16612929) answer?